# Specs2 mockito throws NoSuchMethodError

Tags: scala, mockito, sbt, specs2

I have a Scala project based on play framework. I am using specs2 mockito and specifications for test cases. When running the test cases, I am getting following error:

```
Exception in thread "specs2-7" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'scala.collection.immutable.Stream org.specs2.data.Trees$Treex.flattenLeft()'
  | => cat org.specs2.reporter.JUnitDescriptions.fragmentDescriptions(JUnitDescriptions.scala:69)
    at org.specs2.reporter.JUnitDescriptions.fragmentDescriptions$(JUnitDescriptions.scala:68)
    at org.specs2.reporter.JUnitDescriptions$.fragmentDescriptions(JUnitDescriptions.scala:115)
    at org.specs2.reporter.JUnitXmlPrinter.descriptions(JUnitXmlPrinter.scala:52)
    at org.specs2.reporter.JUnitXmlPrinter.descriptions$(JUnitXmlPrinter.scala:51)
    at org.specs2.reporter.JUnitXmlPrinter$.descriptions(JUnitXmlPrinter.scala:117)
    at org.specs2.reporter.JUnitXmlPrinter.$anonfun$saveResults$1(JUnitXmlPrinter.scala:35)
    at org.specs2.control.eff.EffImplicits$$anon$1.bind(Eff.scala:163)
    at org.specs2.control.eff.EffImplicits$$anon$1.bind(Eff.scala:141)
    at org.specs2.control.origami.Fold$$anon$2.end(Fold.scala:44)
```

**Details:**

- Play Framework version: 2.8.19
- scala version: 2.12.17
- java version: 17
- specs2-mock: 4.13.3
- specs2-core: 4.13.3
- `scalacOptions:=Seq("-release", "17")`

I have also tried upgrading specs2 version from `4.13.3` to `4.17.0` and then to `4.20.0` but didn't work.

My demo test case looks like this.

```scala
import org.specs2.mock.Mockito
import org.specs2.mutable.Specification


class DemoTest extends Specification with Mockito {

  isolated


  "DemoTest.calculate" should {

    """ return 5""" in {

      val demo = new Demo()

      demo.run() shouldEqual 5
    }

  }

}
```

I have also taken care of the things required to run Play framework using java17.https://github.com/playframework/playframework/releases/2.8.15

What might be the possible cause for it?

I tried upgrading the specs2 version and I was expecting that with most recent play framework version, the updated version of specs2 should fix the issue but that didnt happen.

Comment: If you are using the sbt plugin for play, you should be able to use [Specs2 with mockito](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaTestingWithSpecs2#Using-specs2) just adding `libraryDependencies += specs2 % Test` to your `build.sbt`. Are you adding the dependencies manually? You might have some version conflicts there. Have you run `sbt dependencyTree`?

Comment: hi @GastónSchabas thanks for the reply. I already used it exactly the way you mentioned above but it hangs with the error I mentioned. I tried to remove the play specifications and used specs2 specifications instead, it worked but then there are few new error coming up like error when mocking a method that is supposed to return int value. `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because the return value of "org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.MockMethodInterceptor$DispatcherDefjava.lang.reflect.Method, Object[], java.util.concurrent.Callable)" is null `

Comment: Please edit your post providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Just with those errors without knowing how you setup the project and how the tests are written is hard to imagine what is happening